# how to override a user control in asp web forms?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

i have a .aspx page, where i have some user controls, nested inside `<table>` tags, some of them are link this:

```
<td runat="server" id="LoadContext" class="tb_RightTD">
<cc1:RMWDropDownMenu ID="ddLoadContext" CssClass="ddLoadContext" CaptionCssClass="lbContext" CaptionExpandedCSSClass="lbContextExpanded" ImageCssClass="lbContextImage" ImageExpandedCSSClass="lbContextImageExpanded" runat="server" DropDownContentsBoxWidth="0px" DropDownMenuCellCssClass="DropDownMenuCell" DropDownMenuItemCssClass="DropDownMenuItemCssClass" DropDownMenuItemHoverCssClass="DropDownMenuItemHoverCssClass" DropDownMenuTableCssClass="DropDownMenuTable" meta:resourcekey="ddLoadContextResource1" TableCssClass="dropDownTable" Value="" DropDownContentsPanelId="" ExpandImagePath="" TableExpandedCssClass=""></cc1:RMWDropDownMenu>
</td>
```

i can't understand how this works, because, i'm just changing the "frontend", and... this code generates a table soup with some links inside. i want change the structure of this "dropdown" and in his place, use bootstrap structure, to make it look better, i need some help to override this thing, i know php, but asp is not my beach.

[folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dME5Y.png)

here the page i'm editing: http://pastebin.com/kgsMk2mH

Comment: oh and my project is a compiled web project

Comment: Well, if its already a compiled project, you can just change some styling of your user control may be in ascx or using css file.

Comment: seriously? i'm sad now... i not have the source files to edit the master page, so, i'm just stuck here trying to do something, but nothing what i try works. someone tell me to try decompile dll files to edit the user control, but i think this will not solve my problem too

Comment: Let me know what exactly do you have within user control and how do you want to change?

Comment: updated the question with the code linked at paste bin